# how update state in rtk query by useEffect

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

i have two endpoints when i add new value to endpoint one i want endpoint two updated by useEffect Hook

```js
const PostDetails = (props) => {
   const id = props.match.params.id;

   const [addNewComment, { isSuccess: success, isError }] = useAddNewCommentMutation();

 

   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const selectPost = useMemo(() => postApi.endpoints.getPost.select(id), [id]);
   const { data: post, isLoading } = useSelector(selectPost);

   useEffect(() => {
      const result = dispatch(postApi.endpoints.getPost.initiate(id));

      return result.unsubscribe;
   }, [id, dispatch, success]);
```

it said
name(pin):"ConditionError"
message(pin):"Aborted due to condition callback returning false."

Answer (score 2):

That just means "there is already data and I have no reason to assume it is outdated, I'm not gonna fetch again".

You **can** do a

```js
dispatch(postApi.endpoints.getPost.initiate(id, {forceRefetch: true}));
```

but that's not what you should do here.

What you really should use this is the `invalidation` feature.

So your endpoint `getPost` has a `providesTags` function that returns `[{ type: 'Post', id: 5 }]` and your `addNewComment` mutation has an `invalidatesTags` function that returns `[{ type: 'Post', id: 5 }]`, too.

That way, whenever you call that `addNewComment` mutation, the `getPost` endpoint will refetch.

Please read the documentation chapter about [Automated Refetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching)

Comment: thanks your answer solved my problem addnewcomment it independent table not with post table for than reason i need to refetch getPost

Comment: Usually you should have only one API in your application, we state that at many places throughout the documentation. Only use more than one `createApi` call if you have completely unrelated data, like one api accessing data from facebook and the other one accessing twitter. Your data here is obviously not unrelated or you would not need to trigger that refetch.
You can still split up that one api using the code splitting approaches, but automated invalidation will work.